# File created from FileSavePicker not allowing to copy data on it

Tags: c#, file, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am using a FileSavePicker in my UWP app using which user can backup sqlite database file. The problem is that once user saves the file and I try to copy the sqlite file on the newly created file, I get UnauthorizedAccessException.

```
var file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

if (file != null)
{
   CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(file);
   //Exception on line below
   await Task.Run(() => File.Copy(file.Path, dbFilePath, true));
   FileUpdateStatus status = await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(file);
}
```

The Exception I am getting is,

```
{"Access to the path 'C:\\Users\\CurrentUser\\Desktop\\BackupFile.sqlite' is denied."}
```

As far as I have read about UWP apps, the application can access the path/file which is coming from FileSavePicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UWP you can't access files by their filepath, the app doesn't have privileges (thus some methods from *File* class are useless) - you should access files via *StorageFile* (it's using a broker). In your case you should open *Streams* for both files and copy them. Something like this:

```
using (var writeStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
using (var readStream = await dbFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
{
    await readStream.CopyToAsync(writeStream);
}
```